# How to customize application menu for java application in Mac OS

Tags: java, macos

Hi I have created a java application. I found there is an application menu and about application in Mac. I donot know how to customize those about application dialog. i Want to write my own dialog instead of that dialog. How to do this. 
I found that I have to use Application Adapter.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tutorial: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac2/
code sample: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/MacOSApplicationAdapter.htm